# Photoshop Automation won't let me choose a filename

Tags: automation, photoshop

Hey,
today I tried to create a photoshop automation that saves me an area of an image that i've masked.

The Steps are:
Copy Flattened (CTRL+CMD+C), 
New File, 
Paste, 
Save For Web, 
Close without save

My Problem: The Save for Web Step always choose the same filename and overwrites the old file without question.
How do I get Photoshop to do all the steps but ask me for the filename to use?

greetings,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a "pause" option in the macro explorer, click it next your save-as action.

[image]